# Trigger updates all value from table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I've written a trigger that must update CCCMPMTRL table when the column PRICER01 from MTRL table updates. The primary key from the table MTRL is also a column named MTRL which I also keep in the table that must update (CCCMPMTRL) as a foreign key. The thing is that whenever I update the MTRL table, in the CCCMPMTRL, values update for all the records I have in MTRL, but I want for one only, the current one. What do I do wrong?

Code looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.[test_Price]
ON dbo.[MTRL]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @MTRL INT;
    DECLARE @OLDPRICER01 FLOAT(2);
    DECLARE @NEWPRICER01 FLOAT(2);
    DECLARE @MPMTRL INT;
    SET @MTRL = (SELECT I.MTRL FROM INSERTED I,MTRL M WHERE M.MTRL = I.MTRL);
    SET @MPMTRL = (SELECT MTRL FROM MTRL WHERE MTRL=@MTRL);
    SET @OLDPRICER01 = (SELECT PRICER01 FROM MTRL WHERE MTRL =@MTRL AND SODTYPE = 51)
    SET @NEWPRICER01 = (SELECT PRICER01 FROM INSERTED WHERE MTRL = @MTRL AND SODTYPE = 51)
    IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT CM.MTRL FROM CCCMPMTRL CM, INSERTED I WHERE CM.MTRL = I.MTRL))
        INSERT INTO CCCMPMTRL
            SELECT M.MTRL,D.PRICER01,I.PRICER01 FROM INSERTED I, DELETED D, MTRL M WHERE I.MTRL = @MTRL
    ELSE
        IF(@OLDPRICER01 <> @NEWPRICER01)
            UPDATE CCCMPMTRL 
            SET OLDPRICER01 = @OLDPRICER01,
                NEWPRICER01 = @NEWPRICER01
                    FROM CCCMPMTRL AS CM 
                    WHERE CM.MTRL = @MTRL
```

Comment: Just a side note - trigger can be fired for multiple rows at once, thereby you need to use set based operations (or atleast cursors) to process all affected records.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` can contain 0, 1, or *multiple* rows. As such, assigning values to scalar variable like `SET @MTRL = (SELECT I.MTRL FROM INSERTED I,MTRL M WHERE M.MTRL = I.MTRL)` is inherently wrong-headed.

Comment: The update event triggers in a program that has a button 'Save'. So, when i press the button the update occurs for table MTRL only for one row. Is it possible that INSERTED can contain more than one row?

Comment: Even if your current use case only changes one row at a time, writing a trigger that will fail, silently, to do the correct thing for multi-row updates will... not make you very popular with any future maintainers.

Comment: I want this trigger to change only one row, the row that has the primary key from the table MTRL equal with the foreign key MTRL from CCCMPMTRL. The thing is that right now this trigger updates all values from CCCMPMTRL even if thsi table is empty. This trigger should update the CCCMPMTRL table if it finds an existing MTRL from the primary table MTRL or should insert a new MTRL if it doesn't find one...

Comment: Is there only record for each MTRL value in CCCMPMTRL? I am asking this as you are trying to update same record for each update in MTRL table for given MTRL  field.

Comment: Yes, there is only one record. The table MTRL contains articles with prices. So, for each primary key there is only one article.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE CM
    SET OLDPRICER01 = D.PRICER01,
        NEWPRICER01 = I.PRICER01
    FROM INSERTED I
        JOIN DELETED D ON D.MTRL=I.MTRL
        JOIN CCCMPMTRL CM ON CM.MTRL=I.MTRL
    WHERE D.PRICER01 <> I.PRICER01

INSERT INTO CCCMPMTRL
    SELECT I.MTRL, D.PRICER01, I.PRICER01 
    FROM INSERTED I
        JOIN DELETED D ON D.MTRL=I.MTRL
        LEFT JOIN CCCMPMTRL C ON C.MTRL=I.MTRL
    WHERE C.MTRL IS NULL
```

Because the UPDATE statement uses an inner join on CCMPMTRL it will only update where a row already exists, whereas the INSERT statement uses a left outer join to exclude existing values of MTRL.

This should work whether you are inserting one or many rows at once, and there is no need for all those local variables.

Comment: Thank you! This trigger works when I update manually the MTRL table from sql query. But when I press the save button from the application it gives me an error so there is probably an issue on the event button that i have to fix. But, thank you so much for this!!